# How do i transfer an app that has been downloaded to the PC iTunes Store to my iPhone 5?

Tags: ios-appstore

I downloaded Real Racing from PC iTunes Store.

How do I transfer it to my iPhone? I see a `Cloud sign in` in the app on the iPhone but when I press it, it asks me to be connected to WiFi but I don't have a WiFi connection but mobile data is available.

Comment: By "PC iTunes Store" you mean iTunes on your PC? So you are looking for a way to get the app from the PC to the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Real Racing, if I recall, is too large to transfer to your phone over the air unless you're connected to Wi-Fi. So, you will need to use iTunes to install it to your phone (unless you find a Wi-Fi Hotspot to use.)